# GET_SEARCH_RESULTS webservice response says ivalid QueryText

Tags: xml, web-services, soa, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-ucm

Used below xml request to get the details of a document in the UCM:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ucm="http://www.oracle.com/UCM">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ucm:GenericRequest webKey="cs"> <!-- Fixed value -->
         <ucm:Service IdcService="GET_SEARCH_RESULTS"><!--  -->

            <ucm:Document>
                <ucm:Field name="SearchEngineName">database</ucm:Field>

               <ucm:Field name="QueryText">dDocTitle &lt;contains&gt; 'Test' </ucm:Field>

            </ucm:Document>
         </ucm:Service>
      </ucm:GenericRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response is:

```
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <env:Header/>
       <env:Body>
          <ns2:GenericResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/UCM">
             <ns2:Service IdcService="GET_SEARCH_RESULTS">
                <ns2:Document>
                   <ns2:Field name="StatusCode">-1</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="IdcService">GET_SEARCH_RESULTS</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="SortOrder">Desc</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="SearchEngineIsDefault">1</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="validateSearchQuery">false</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="StatusMessageKey">!csUnableToRetrieveSearchResults!csSearchInvalidQueryText</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="EnterpriseSearchMaxRows">4</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="idcToken"/>
                   <ns2:Field name="FullRequest">&amp;QueryText=dDocTitle+%3ccontains%3e+%27Test%27&amp;SortField=dInDate&amp;SortOrder=Desc&amp;SearchEngineName=database</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="localizedForResponse">1</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="useOnlyLocalForDpTrigger">1</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="SearchEngineName">database</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="SortField">dInDate</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="UnparsedQueryText">dDocTitle &lt;contains> 'Test'</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="OriginalUnencodedQueryText">dDocTitle &lt;contains> 'Test'</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="queryDefinitionLabel">DATABASE.METADATA.ORACLE</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="ComputedSearchEngineName">DATABASE.METADATA</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="OriginalQueryText">dDocTitle+%3ccontains%3e+%27Test%27</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="refreshMonikers"/>
                   <ns2:Field name="refreshSubMonikers"/>
                   <ns2:Field name="changedMonikers"/>
                   <ns2:Field name="IsOracle">1</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="StatusMessage">Unable to retrieve search results. The query text is invalid.</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="QueryText">dDocTitle &lt;contains> 'Test'</ns2:Field>
                   <ns2:Field name="escapeReservedStringsInSearch">false</ns2:Field>
```

It seems that the xml escape has not worked  for < symbol. Is there any reason this is not working? or am I missing something? 
When the QueryText is just "dDocTitle" the code works and response contains the details of al docs in ucm but however, the filter condition is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The < and > might be the issue, but there is another problem - the quotes are not correct. Replace ' (apostrophe) with ` (back tick) in the query.

Comment: I changed the '(apostrophe) to the `(back tick) in the request, the issue still remains, the response is the same with just the ' (apostrophe) changed to the  `( back tick)

Comment: The request is working now, the working QueryText is ``<ucm:Field name="QueryText">dDocTitle &lt;Sustring&gt; `Test`</ucm:Field>`` . Thanks for the tip @Sam